# htaccess redirect specific files in subfolders to a script

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have some files with .exe extension in subfolder /files/

I would like to redirect all queries

```
/files/somename.exe
```

to

```
/script.php?name=somename
```

Also I have a root .htaccess and local .htaccess in /files/ folder.
I think I should change local .htaccess, but it doesn't work.

what i tried -

```
RedirectMatch ./([_A-Za-z0-9-]+).exe$ /script.php?name=$1
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/files/([_A-Za-z0-9-]+)\.exe$ /script.php?name=$1
```

OR if you want internal rewrite only then put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^files/([\w-]+)\.exe$ script.php?name=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: it doesn't help:( Iforgot to mentin that in .htaccess in /files/ folder has 'RewriteRule ^([_A-Za-z0-9-]+).exe/?$ http://www.example.com/script.php?name=$1' it is used for files.example.com domain